# Cannot get DWA-142 to work on 13.04

Tags: wireless, usb

I need help installing a DLINK DWA-142 Wireless USB Adapter in Ubuntu 13.04. I already installed ndiswrapper and tried both netmw245.inf and mrvw245.inf drivers.

Result of `ndiswrapper -l` (respectively):

```
netmw245 : driver installed
device (07D1:3B10) present
mrvw245 : driver installed
device (07D1:3B10) present
```

Result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:3b10 D-Link System DWA-142 RangeBooster N Adapter [Marvell 88W8362+88W8060]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Result of `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Still no wlan0. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try uninstalling `ndiswrapper` drivers, and see if Ubuntu detects itself the device.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Braiam.

The fact is Ubuntu 13.04 does not recognize this adapter by itself. I installed it a week ago, with both ethernet cable and DWA-142 pluged in. Installed all the updates and Ubuntu still wouldn't recognize the wireless adapter.

Hence I decided do go for ndiswrapper. I tried both the above mentioned Windows drivers, but I always got the same result.

Maybe I'm missing a step or something, but I can't figure out which...